# Remove "Some" keyword from string println! in rust

Tags: rust

I want to print out the value of `sys.host_name()`

```rust
let hostname = sys.host_name();

println!("{:?}", hostname);
```

Output: "Some("arch")"
Expected output: "arch"

How can i print the "raw" string?

Comment: `sys.host_name.unwrap()`

Comment: What do you want to do if `sys.host_name()` fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears (not sure what library you are using) `sys.host_name()` does not return a string, rather an `Option<String>`, which implies the function could fail (and return `None` instead of `Some("arch")`.

`println!` is printing the full type. If you just wish to print the contained string, you need to extract the string from the `Option`. One possible way:

```rust
let possible_hostname = sys.host_name();

// Check if the hostname is Some or None
if let Some(hostname) = possible_hostname {
    println!("{:?}", hostname);
}
else {
    println!("hostname could not be determined");
}
```

If you would prefer your program to just panic if the hostname is `None`, you can "unwrap" the option:

```rust
let hostname = sys.host_name().unwrap();

println!("{:?}", hostname);
```

Comment: Another option is to set `hostname` to some default value if the function returned `None`, e.g.: `let hostname = sys.host_name().unwrap_or ("<unknown>".to_string());`